# Finding a Jar that contains Main: Shell Scripting

Tags: shell, scripting, grep, pipe

I want to write a shell script that can help me find the jar that contains Main. 
I had been thinking of:

```
find . -name "*.jar" | jar -tvf | grep Main
```

This seems to be incorrect because jar -tvf takes in one input at a time and pipes create full output at once. Is there a possibility to make pipes work serially?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using bash you can use this script using process substitution:

```
while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do
   if jar -tf "$file" | grep -q 'Main'; then
      echo "$file has Main"
      break
   fi
done < <(find . -name "*.jar" -print0)
```

For non-bash use:

```
find . -name "*.jar" -print0 |
while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do
   if jar -tf "$file" | grep -q 'Main'; then
      echo "$file has Main"
      break
   fi
done
```

Comment: Its giving java.util.zip.ZipExcpetion: error in opening zip file at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open, ....

Comment: Ah I had missing `$` in `$file`, try now